# HTML Redirect Dependent on Device Type

Tags: html, web-frontend, http-equiv

I have a very simple webpage:

```
<html>
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Refresh" content="0; url='https://www.website1.com'" />
</head>
<body>
</body>
</html>
```

Instead of this always redirecting to the same website, I would like to redirect to either website1 or website2 depending on if the user is on a mobile device or a browser on their computer. I am new to front-end web development, so any help you could provide would be much appreciated.

Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should use Javascript for that. Check for device type based on the `userAgent`, and then redirect to the new website

```html
<script>
if( /Android|webOS|iPhone|iPad|iPod|BlackBerry|IEMobile|Opera Mini/i.test(navigator.userAgent) ) {
 // redirects if mobile
 window.location('https://example.com')
} else {
  // redirects if whatever else
  window.location('https://example2.com')
}
</script>
```

Comment: Thank you! I needed to change this slightly to `window.location = "/myroute"`.

Comment: sorry about that, I mistyped

Comment: much obliged for this sire